# What would make development with SharePoint easier?

Tags: sharepoint

What would make development with SharePoint easier?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A better product.

Right now it is to many things that doesn't behave as a development environment should.

1. Dispose of objects
2. Performance of traversing small lists with 3000/4000 items
3. Lack of support of transactions

Hopefully next version will have the SQLServer based lists where you can have transactional support and better performance......

Bill G raised the question in feb 2008 that it is something strange with Sharepoint that you get problems when you have 3000 items in a list and SQL Server easily supports million of items....

---

Comment: Wasd today listen to Martin Fowler who spoke about when software doesn't have the optimal design and when you should add new functionality you have to pay a cost which you don't have to pay if the software was better designed.

Th term for this is design debt and that is what we have in the Sharepoint product hopefully 2010 will change that 

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/edge/09/jun09/designdebteconomics/index.html

Answer (score 8):

The build and deployment process needs to be simplified. There are numerous tools available to create WSP files, but they are all decent at one thing another, but you ultimately need to extend or rework the solution WSP deployment package for you environment.

Answer (score 6):

Standard HTML and better support for the DOM.

Answer (score 5):

**Informative error messages.**
While easier debugging and less XML are very tempting (as people suggested), I would settle for something much more modest.
SharePoint usually "swallows" exceptions or other error messages. Very often when a customized page or a web part fails, you get an obscure 'page cannot be displayed' message. With luck, the designer will direct you to the problem, or you might find some details on the logs or the system event viewer. But in many cases you have nothing.
Examples - Business data catalog xml monstrosity that worked on the editor but not on the site, xml web parts that fail randomly, xsl typos or mistakes, etc. All take much longer to find than they should, and some are impossible to debug.

Comment: I hate that "value does not fall within the expected range" exception that pops up whenever something goes wrong in the API.

Answer (score 3):

Remote Deployment:
- 1 central Sharepoint, and transparent remote debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Less XML (schema.xml etc).

Answer (score 3):

Making the dev process more like "traditional" asp.net development, in other words making the integration with VS better. You should develop against SharePoint from within VS not from within SharePoint (ie SPD).
SPVisualDev on codeplex has made that process better but I hope (an I say hope) for better support within VS2010 together with SP2010.

Answer (score 1):

Should check out @SPDevWiki's page on this also http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7340352

Answer (score -1):

Less people trying to abuse the product would make things a lot easier too ;)

Comment: Oh negative feedback without a comment? boo
IMO it's a common source of problems.. people trying to fit the square SharePoint peg in the round hole of their problem..